# Is there a way to COPY a file from parent image in docker to child image on build?

Tags: docker, parent-child, dockerfile

I'm trying to make base image (parent image) in docker. When I use `COPY` to copy some files into child docker image it does not copy that file.

Is there a way to copy a file from parent Dockerfile folder to child Dockerfile?

**Parent Dockerfile:**

```
FROM debian:jessie-slim

ONBUILD RUN mkdir /app
ONBUILD WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
```

I have a file in base image called `package.json`. First I used `ONBUILD COPY . .` to copy that file from the base directory to the child image. I didn't `COPY` anything. So I thought it is related to `ONBUILD` and does not see those files, so I removed it but that didn't help neither.

My directories:

```
base_dir
    Dockerfile
    package.json

child_dir
    Dockerfile
    my_app
```

This is the structure of the images folders for building docker files.

Comment: When you build an image `FROM` a parent image, the "child" image contains all the files that are in the parent image. Perhaps you can explain a bit more what you're trying to do, and what isn't working?

Comment: @thaJeztah I actually want to copy from a base directory to the image I am building. I cannot copy that file into the base image when I'm trying to build it. Please the question. I have added some extra information which could be helpful.

Comment: The file is there in your parent image. But since you use `COPY . .`, it is there is the folder `/` which the default folder of debian image. In your child image you are in `/app` and the file would be available in `/package.json`

Comment: @TarunLalwani thank you! You hit the nail in the head! it was copied into `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is there in your parent image. But since you use COPY . ., it is there is the folder working directory of the parent image.  `/` is the default working directory of debian image.

In your child image you are in `/app` directory by default and the file would be available in `/package.json`